# && together method invocations for Enumerable elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Is there an elegant Ruby way to invoke a method (that returns a boolean) for each element of an Enumerable, but && the results together? A bit like `Array#collect` but returning an overall boolean result rather than an array.

Comment: Sounds like [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I've found a similar question and closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I couldn't find any similar questions, but that's just because of the way I expressed mine.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).